# Como organizar productos en Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css

Buenos días actualmente estoy presentando este problema al organizar mis productos;

```html
  <div class='row'>
                      <div class='thumbnail'>

    <div class='col-md-4'>
       <img style='width:250px;'  src='{$fila['img_producto']}' alt=''>
   
    <div class='col-md-4'>
     <h4>{$fila['titulo_producto']}</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
       <p> {$fila['descripcion_producto']}
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
       Disponible hasta las {$fila['hora_max_producto']}</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-4'>
<a data-toggle='modal' href='#comprar' class='btn btn-primary btn-lg'>Comprar</a>
```

He actualizado el codigo, sin embargo ahora agrega cada producto que agrego en una fila, debo tener 3 productos en 1 fila, por favor ayúdenme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día,  en mis búsquedas de como resolver algunas situaciones relacionadas al desarrollo existe un tema controversia sobre que es mejor, si utilizar tablas o hacer uso de css , hay algunos videos en youtube que te podrían ayudar con el css.

Comment: Elimina los width que tienes en la clase thumbnail, deja que tome el 100% de la columna padre

Comment: Las columnas deben sumar 12, si tienes 3, col-md-4 a cada una y ya. Revisa la documentación de bootstrap, ahí está todos los detalles. :)

Comment: He actualizado el código, si bien ahora está todo más organizado me agrega 1 producto por fila, necesito que muestre 3 productos por fila :(

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provee un sistema de grillas bastante fácil de entender, en donde tienes filas (rows) y dentro de las filas tienemos las columnas (col)

Teniendo esto en cuenta te recomiendo que crees una fila (row) para tus tarjetas y a cada tarjeta le asignes un espacio de 4 (col-lg-4), de la siguiente forma

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <img style='width:250px;'  src='{$fila['img_producto']}' 
     alt=''>
    <h4>{$fila['titulo_producto']}</h4>
    <p> {$fila['descripcion_producto']}</p>
    <p>Disponible hasta las {$fila['hora_max_producto']}</p>
    <a data-toggle='modal' href='#comprar' class='btn btn-primary 
    btn-lg'>Comprar</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <img style='width:250px;'  src='{$fila['img_producto']}' 
     alt=''>
    <h4>{$fila['titulo_producto']}</h4>
    <p> {$fila['descripcion_producto']}</p>
    <p>Disponible hasta las {$fila['hora_max_producto']}</p>
    <a data-toggle='modal' href='#comprar' class='btn btn-primary 
    btn-lg'>Comprar</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <img style='width:250px;'  src='{$fila['img_producto']}' 
     alt=''>
    <h4>{$fila['titulo_producto']}</h4>
    <p> {$fila['descripcion_producto']}</p>
    <p>Disponible hasta las {$fila['hora_max_producto']}</p>
    <a data-toggle='modal' href='#comprar' class='btn btn-primary 
    btn-lg'>Comprar</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

De esta forma tendrías 3 productos por fila
Te dejo la documentación de las grillas de Bootstrap para que le eches un vistazo.[Documentacion grid Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

por lo que veo con tu actualizacion te hace cerrar en div que tiene la class row, te faltan varias etiquetas de cierre